# Aged Receivable report total amount is different in general ledger account odoo14

Tags: odoo, accounting

When I check  aged receivable report with general ledger, why the amount is different.I used account receivable account for customer invoice and when I checked account receivable account in general ledger, the amount is different.My logic is something wrong? Can we check aged receivable with general ledger, right?

Answer (score 0):

Reasons why the accounts receivable report could be different within A/R from what is shown in the general ledger (GL) include any transaction that is only within A/R, and was (correctly or incorrectly) never carried over to the GL.

This is usually something like:

A customer underpaid an invoice by a small amount which was written off, and if that write off was not posted to GL

A late fee being added to a customer's balance, but not posted to the GL

If a customer has two different customer accounts (by accident usually), and you're only reviewing one in A/R, but the GL includes both

Sometimes a GL amount for 'accounts receivable' might include the 'trade receivable' amount (related to customer transactions as well as misc receivables - like an amount due from an employee, or other unusual transactions.